# Conditionally transform a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector

```
y = c(1.2,14,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.8)
```

And i want to transform it into $(number)M if it is above 0.5, and $(number)K if it is below 0.5.

I've tried this but cant get it to be conditional:

```
paste0("$",round(y,1),"M")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ifelse`

```
ifelse(y  > 0.5, paste0("$", y, "M"), paste0("$", y, "K"))
```

---

Or without `ifelse`

```
paste0("$", y, c("K", "M")[(y > 0.5) + 1])
```

Comment: Cheers. I went with your first one cause i needed to do some formatting to the number if it was under 0.5. Like this: ifelse(y>=0.5, paste0("$", round(..y..,1), "M"), paste0("$", round(..y..,3)*1000, "K"))